# DllImport types for char **result, unsigned int * length

Tags: c#, dllimport

I'm trying to call this function from unmanaged dll:

```
gvRenderData(GVC_t *gvc, Agraph_t* g, char *format, char **result, unsigned int *length)
```

I use DllImport:

```
[DllImport(FolderName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int gvRenderData(IntPtr gvc, IntPtr g, string format, out IntPtr result, out int length);
```

and I got exception

> Attempted to read or write protected memory.

I think my type for char result or for unsigned int length is invalid.

Comment: Pretty low odds you can pinvoke this correctly, those two first arguments surely are trouble.  You'll need an unmanaged debugger to see what causes the kaboom in the native code.